# comparison between arrays of two tables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop

I am staring into this one for hours. I am not able to find the mistake. Can anyone tell me what wrong did I do? Or is there a better way to compare?

```
$res1=mysql_query(**query for table1**);
$n1=mysql_num_rows($res1);
$res2=mysql_query(**query for table 2**);
$n2=mysql_num_rows($res2);

for($i=0;$i<$n1;$i++)
{
    $r1=mysql_fetch_row($res1);

    for($j=0;$j<$n2;$j++)
    {
        $r2=mysql_fetch_row($res2);
        if($r1[0]==$r2[0])
        {
            echo $r1[0]."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

table 1 contains these elements: 1,2,3,16,18,19,20,21,22,24,23
table 2 contains : 23,21

However, the program returns zero matches. Why?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what is happening here is

1. you are looping over all hte elements of result 1 correctly, but you a re not looping over all the elements of result two correctly.

The result two elements are getting exhausted in the first iteration.

from the example data you have posted, here is the looping:

when r1 is 1,

r2 is 23,21

when r1 is 2,

r2 is exhausted.

To reset result two again, you will have to do

mysql_data_seek($res2,0);
each time

i.e your for loop will look like this

```
for($i=0;$i<$n1;$i++) {

    $r1=mysql_fetch_row($res1);

    mysql_data_seek($res2,0);
    for($j=0;$j<$n2;$j++)     {
        $r2=mysql_fetch_row($res2);
        if($r1[0]==$r2[0])         {
           echo $r1[0]."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the database do the join in a single query. That's what they are made for, and they typically use more efficient algorithms, e.g., if an index is available.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is an `INNER JOIN`. A `JOIN` is a fundamental component of a relational database that allows data from multiple tables to be intersected in varying ways.

My favorite explanation of `JOIN`s is actually from the [Bugzilla documentation](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/developer.html#sql-join) -- they do a great job explaining all the different types.

In your case, your query will look something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    table1.field1, table1.field2, ...,
    table2.field2, table2.field2, ...
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id)
```

I've created an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8c93/1/0) for your perusal.